# "Ingredient" or "product"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I want to create a database with products/ingredients where it will include all things from raw carrots to cheeseburgers from McDonalds or Coca Cola, all in one database.

Users will be able to add their own recipes, where they will have to select products/ingredients.

Which term is more appropriate for that database? **Products** or **ingredients**?

Answer (score 1):

'Products' implies something that is produced, and is a possible word to use for the end results of a recipe (i.e. a cheeseburger). An ingredient is something that might be used as part of a recipe, such as hamburger or cheese. Unfortunately, some items might fit both words, such as cheese. Cheese can be eaten by itself or used in a recipe to make a cheeseburger.

To answer your question, if you are putting recipes, ingredients and products all in one database, I would call it either a recipe or a food database.

Comment: Ingredients and products will be in one database, recipes will be in the other one and it will be called recipes. Hmm maybe food is right word for ingredients and products